# How to sort files by created date in Voyager Storage

Tags: laravel-5.6, voyager

As stated in the title...

How can I sort files by created date in Voyager Storage using Laravel?

Currently it is sorted by oldest files and newest last, but I want to make it so that newest files are shown first.

I have looked through the Voyager documentation but could not find anything useful.

I am using Laravel 5.6 and Voyager 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you must look at the [DataType](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.1/src/Models/DataType.php) model, [browse.blade](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.1/resources/views/bread/browse.blade.php) view template, and [VoyagerBaseControlller](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.1/src/Http/Controllers/VoyagerBaseController.php).

Hope my answer could help.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Not quite the right place but it gave an idea where to look in to it. Since files inside the vendor folder are 'non-project' files, I had to copy functions that I needed to override and paste in the controller.